# Environment variable JAVA_HOME does not point to valid JVM in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, jvm

Trying to start Android Studio, it says error launching studio:-

[image]

My JDK:-

[image]

Comment: There's a semi-colon `;` at the end of your JAVA_HOME variable.

Comment: Removed semi-colon, then also same error @1615903

Comment: try removing \bin from the end of the path